# Visual Studio 2013 Debugger não funciona com DLL externa

Tags: c#, debug, dll

Possuo uma aplicação que foi migrada de VS2008 para 2013, .Net FrameWork 4 e C#,
que utiliza uma DLL de outro projeto.

Build sem erros. Porém após execução, no momento de instanciar o objeto da dll, ele apresenta o seguinte erro (Esse erro só ocorre no *debugger*).

> Erro: Não é possível carregar a DLL 'PegasusImaging.Common.BarcodeXpress5.5.0.12.0.ssm': Não foi possível encontrar o módulo especificado. 
>   (Exceção de HRESULT: 0x8007007E)"

Caso, eu publique o projeto, ele funciona normalmente.

Lembrando que este mesmo projeto executa normalmente em Visual Studio 2008.

Pode ser algum problema com o *debugger* do Visual Studio 2013?

Comment: Isso é um sintoma de que a DLL está presente no ambiente de publicação, mas não está presente na pasta/ficheiro `bin` da sua aplicação quando você a executa pelo Visual Studio. Como você a executa? A DLL está presente no ambiente em que ocorre falha?

Comment: Renan, a dll já está na pasta /bin do projeto.

Comment: Você não tem permissão de acesso à pasta onde a DLL está.

Comment: Já coloquei a permissão e ainda assim, continua não funcionando.
Alguém tem mais alguma ideia?
abs.